# How do I get color coded console output from SBT on Windows?

Tags: windows, scala, sbt

I'm using SBT (Simple Build Tool) to build my Scala projects on Windows. I've seen that one of my friends, that runs OSX, gets color coded output in his terminal windows when running SBT, but mine is just the same color everywhere. Is there any way to enable this for Windows?

Answer (score 3):

For DOS shell, check out **[ansicon](http://www.marioawad.com/2010/11/16/ansi-command-line-colors-under-windows/)**

- [download page](http://adoxa.110mb.com/ansicon/index.html)
- type in the DOS shell:

```
   ansicon -i
```

(If the above links don't work too well, [aeracode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/326874/aeracode) mentiones in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629918/how-do-i-get-color-coded-console-output-from-sbt-on-windows/4301018#comment16756241_4301018) [this address](http://adoxa.3eeweb.com/ansicon/index.html))

[image]

(this picture is not from a sbt session but illustrates colors within a DOS session)

Comment: Here is link to [index page](http://adoxa.3eeweb.com/ansicon/index.html) of `ansicon` (if some troubles with links above will occur).

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to install a POSIX-layer like MinGW or Cygwin and add `-Djline.terminal=jline.UnixTerminal` as a parameter to `java` to your sbt startup script.

I do not know if JLine supports colored output on Windows natively though.

Comment: FWIW, this fails hard from Command Prompt.  It tries to output UNIX color-code sequences which come out literally in Command Prompt.  It also messes with exiting SBT with Ctrl-D.  Beyond that, it fails to load as SBT seems to assume "sh" is the command-shell.

Comment: SBT seems to have a lot of platform-sniffing.  I can't get it to work at all in mingw.  It seems to assume drive-letter path access and breaks from that point on.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get color output on windows by using Minnty with Cygwin.  See the following question for the script to execute sbt from minnty

[how to get specs2 color support on windows using mingw and sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864236/how-to-get-specs2-color-support-on-windows-using-mingw-and-sbt/7866790#7866790)