# SBT has lost its ability to format a screen, with ctrl characters. Why?

Tags: sbt

I really enjoy how the SBT, the Scala Build Tool,
can send out ctrl characters to format a console
window.

But now, I start SBT, on Windows 10,
on a valid project and issue a compile command.  Instead
of the window staying static, as it used to,
now the compiler scrolls the window,
sending lines of control characters, like,

```
C:\daut>sbt
←[0m[←[0m←[0minfo←[0m] ←[0m←[0mwelcome to sbt 1.3.13 (OpenLogic- 
OpenJDK Java 1.8.0-262)←[0m
←[0m[←[0m←[0minfo←[0m] ←[0m←[0mloading global plugins from 
C:\Users\plugins←[0m

or, ←[2K  | => daut / Compile / previousCompile 0s
←[13A←[2K
←[2K
←[2K
```

==============================================
What a disappointment.  Everything else like actual
the compilation seems correct.

Now. Is there some way, to make SBT, not
send out these '←[13A←[2K' characters,
I have reinstalled the software, that is, JAVA,
SBT, Scala, but those changes do not help.

I really enjoyed how SBT, used to perform.
Why?  has SBT lost the ability to
format a console window?  The projects I
am using have been downloaded fresh from github.

Comment: It has nothing to do with scala sbt or java. Your terminal controls the colors. Please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629918/how-do-i-get-color-coded-console-output-from-sbt-on-windows)

Comment: you could add `-Dsbt.log.noformat=true` to SBT_OPTS to disable color formatting completely

Comment: For a short-term workaround, you can also run your command line with `-no-color` to disable fancy formatting.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem (in both cmd.exe and Powershell). Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences#comment92954461_16799175), I edited the registry to add a DWORD named `VirtualTerminalLevel`, value 0x1, under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`.

After restarting cmd.exe/Powershell, both now seem to work.

I don't really understand *why* this helped - and a colleague of mine has it working perfectly under cmd.exe without this registry value.

Comment: How to Add a New DWORD in Regedit:
Launch the Registry Editor by clicking "Start," typing "regedit" in the "Start Search" field and pressing "Enter"

Answer (score 2):

I had exact same problem, it first happened using Powershell so I started using Bash and then there was no display on the command line (https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/4173).
I came back to Powershell and for now is working.

I have also tried the integrated bash terminal on VScode and same problemn that you mentionned.

For now I'm working on VsCode with a Powershell integrated terminal and seems to work. If it helps.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the FAQ](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Faq.html):

> #### How do I disable ansi codes in the output?
>
> Sometimes sbt doesn’t detect that ansi codes aren’t supported and you get output that looks like:
>
> ```
> [0m[ [0minfo [0m]  [0mSet current project to root
> ```
>
> or ansi codes are supported but you want to disable colored output. To completely disable ansi codes, pass `-no-colors` option:
>
> ```
> $ sbt -no-colors
> ```

Comment: This one works for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I also was having the similar issue. By typing `sbt -version` I saw difference in the "sbt version in this project" and "sbt script version". At first I had sbt 1.5.5, then I installed similar version to the project's (sbt 1.3.13).

At the end it looked like this and problem was solved:

```
sbt version in this project: 1.3.13
sbt script version: 1.3.13
```